# Android onTouch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have been searching through the site and haven't quite found what I was looking for. There are 1,000+ posts to look through.  What I am trying to do is get the location of where the user is pressing and based on which quarter of the screen, call another method that will display a new background image.  I know I need to use the `OnTouch` and implement the OnTouchListener at the beginning.  I also know about

```
windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

to figure out the width and height of the screen because different phones have different sizes.  I just cannot seem to be able to put it all together.  Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that deals with retrieving coordinates on the screen when it is pressed. You'll just need to divide the height and width by 2 in order to create your quarters and you'll be on your way.

link: http://blorb.tumblr.com/post/347157141/simple-ontouch-press-and-release-code-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onTouch listener of your view just use this code :

```
String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
```

You will get th X and Y coordinates.